# Mixed caching strategy in PWA service worker

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

some of the urls in my PWA should be network first, and all other should be cache first.

For the network first I want to achive this:

- if successful return network response and update dynamic cache with the latest version of request
- if network request fails, look for match in dynamic cache and return it if it exists, and if not return static fallback file

For cache first:

- Look for match in the dynamic cache, if it exists, return the cached value and update the cached value for the next time
- If dynamic cache doesn't have value, try to get the response from network(with fetch), if it succeeds return network response and update dynamic cache for next time, else return static fallback file

Here is what I've done so far (service worker code):

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
   const url = new URL(event.request.clone().url);
   if (event.request.clone().method === 'POST') {
        // handle post requests
   } else { // handle GET requests
        // network first urls
        if (url.pathname.indexOf("news") > -1 || url.pathname.indexOf("/photos/") > -1) {
          console.log('test'); // this gets logged
          event.respondWith(networkFirst(event));
      } else { 
          event.respondWith(cacheFirst(event));
      }
   }


function networkFirst(event) {
    console.log( 'respond with network first' ); // I can see this
    // Try the network
    return fetch(event.request) // return was edited in
      .then(function(res) {
        return caches.open('CACHE')
          .then(function(cache) {
            // Put in cache if succeeds
            console.log( 'NETWORK RESPONSE' ); // visible
            console.log( res.clone() ); // Response {type: "basic", url: "https://mysite/news", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
            cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
            return res;
          })
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
          // Fallback to cache
          return caches.match(event.request).then(function(res){
              if (res === undefined) { 
                  return caches.open('STATIC_CACHE')
                     .then((cache) => {
                         return caches.match('/offline.html');
                  });
              } 
              return res;
          })
      })   
}

function cacheFirst(event) {
    return caches.open('eyewit') // return was edited in
      .then(function(cache) {

       return cache.match(event.request)
       .then(function(response) {
         var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {

            cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
            return networkResponse;
          }).catch(function () {
              return caches.open('STATIC_CACHE')
                 .then((cache) => {
                     return caches.match('/offline.html');
              });
          });

        // response contains cached data, if available
        return response || fetchPromise;
      })
    })
}
```

When I try any url, for example: mypage/news I get:

> This site can’t be reached

And

> The FetchEvent for "https://mypage/news" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().

Edit:

I've added return statements to beginning of networkFirst and cacheFirst functions, I no longer get page not found, but the site is incredibly slow and a lot of things are not working.
I think that the problem may be in cacheFirst function which returns a promise.

Any help would be appreciated.